# About Extruding Faces

Tags: faces, extrude

As we know, plane kind of meshes have only one face. My mesh has 2 dimentional faces on the edge.I want to give those faces alittle thickness so it would not dissapear when looked from backside. But when i exture the face, it extrudes only edges, not face. i tried it both way. Why does it do that ?

My Mesh:

[image]

Face extruded both way to experiment:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hm. There's a dot that indicates a face, try recalculating normals (select all then Ctrl+N).

Comment: i tried but still same. I have uploaded the mesh and added it to my post in case it is liked to be checked.

Comment: Thanks. Also, for future questions, please note that that particular site has quite broad licensing terms; you can see more [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2413/narrowing-down-terms-of-blend-exchange). Although as long as you know that going in and are OK with it, then it's fine.

Comment: i know but it is not a completed nor complex mesh. So it is ok.

Comment: As you have Backfacing Culling enabled faces with normals pointing in another direction aren't shown (or shown as dot). Looks like you want to solidify the mesh entirely. This is done either with modifier or by extruding all the faces and scaling along their normals; if extruding only some faces you'll get non-manifold geometry.

Comment: Well i made it over. Because applying the first mesh, i made, solidify would create lots of polygons. So first i applied solidify to a simple cylinder and give details on outer surface. So my problem seems to have been fixed. Thank you for answers and i don't know how to close topic since there is no comment i can accept as "answer".

Comment: Comments can't be accepted as answer, there should be actual answer for that below (written in the Add answer box). You can write your own one to show others how you solved the problem; include some screenshots and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i chose those faces and unjoined from rest of mesh and tried again. This time it worked. So it must be faces, next to them, causing the problem. But when i unjoined and extruded those faces, shading looked alittle weird. Also i didn't want to apply solidify to the whole mesh to prevent from unnecessary polygons. In the end, this is what i made.

I made over the mesh.

1.I applied solidify on a basic cylinder

[image]

2.Then gave details to outer face only and my problem seems to have fixed

[image]
[image]